# Java Heap Space (Eclipse and GGTS)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, heap-memory

I'm trying to compile my Grails project on Eclipse and GGTS, and I'm receiving the same error everytime on both platforms:

> Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException:
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

(My laptop has 4GB RAM).

I've activated the Heap Space viewer, and it never reaches the 1GB Max Size I've defined on eclipse.ini and GGTS.ini (it doesn't reach even 400M), so I guess that the problem is that the JVM options on my MAC should be changed.

Eclipse and GGTS values I've set:

> -XX:PermSize=1024M
>
> -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M
>
> -Xms1024M
>
> -Xmx2048M

Default JVM values:

> java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'heapsize|permsize'
>
> uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728       {product}
>
> uintx MaxHeapSize                               = 132120576       {product}
>
> uintx MaxPermSize                               = 85983232        {pd product}
>
> uintx PermSize                                  = 21757952        {pd product}

So, how can i make this change, where's the place to set Heap space globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM used to run Ant scripts is different from the one used to launch Eclipse, therefore the memory settings you have for Eclipse will have no impact on your problem. You need to figure out which JRE is used to run Ant from Eclipse, then you should be able to add default JVM arguments like -Xmx etc.

Alternatively you can create an Ant build configuration in "Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations" and specify JVM arguments in the JRE tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try the recommendation for increasing heap space to Eclipse specified [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F).  I usually will update the values in `eclipse.ini`.